# Change price on a different div using input

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

So I've been trying different fiddles in order to update price as quantity is modified using the +/- buttons.
The problem is, every fiddle I've tried works great OUTSIDE the div, which is formatting the buttons and quantity input.
Any thoughts about making it work inside the div?

Here's my html and script:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 product-details">
    <label class="p-title" style="font-size: 2.4em; font-weight: 300">
        Product Name
    </label>
    <h3 class="p-price" style="color: #21823C; font-size: 2.4em; font-weight: 300; font-style: italic">&#8364;<span id="totalCost">6.90</span></h3>
      <div class="pro-qty">
         <input id="Quantity" tabindex="1" required type="number" value="1" name="quantity" min="1" max="100" step="1">
      </div>
      <div class="quantity col-4">
        <a href="#" class="site-btn" style="margin-top: 9px">ADD TO CART</a>
      </div>        
    </div>
 </div>

    <script>

        $(function ($) {
            var options = {
                minimum: 1,
                maximize: 100,
                onChange: valChanged,
                onMinimum: function(e) {
                    console.log('reached minimum: '+e)
                },
                onMaximize: function(e) {
                    console.log('reached maximize'+e)
                }
            }
            $('#handleCounter').handleCounter(options)
            $('#handleCounter2').handleCounter(options)
            $('#handleCounter3').handleCounter({maximize: 100})
        })
        function valChanged(d) {
    //            console.log(d)
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you tried `$('#mydiv').text(value);` ?

Comment: This code is incomplete. Will not do anything inside or outside a div. Not sure what the issue is. Please share a working sample and the error/issue you are having.

Comment: Sorry about the missing code, you can check the website in simplythe.lu/product.html The counter works fine but price is not updated, can't chance the looks of it. Thanks!